# how can I have a timer in our poll question? Django

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

we have a set of poll questions with a max of 20 questions in the poll, but we will be able to pick up max 5 random questions, and one per stage, but I don't want people to be able to cheat time by just validating client-side, but each question has a time of 1 minute once it expires the next one will be .

models

```
import datetime

from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    duration = models.IntegerField(min=0, max=60)
    code = models.TextField(max_length=1024*2,default='SOME STRING')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

    def was_published_recently(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        return now - datetime.timedelta(days=1) <= self.pub_date <= now

    def choices(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '_choices'):
            self._choices = self.choice_set.all()
        return self._choices

    def max_voted_choice(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '_max_voted_choice'):
            choices = self.choice_set.order_by('-votes')
            if not choices:
                self._max_voted_choice = None
            else:
                self._max_voted_choice = choices[0]
        return self._max_voted_choice



class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

apiviews get random questios from the poll

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status

from .models import Question, Choice
from .serializers import QuestionListPageSerializer, QuestionDetailPageSerializer, ChoiceSerializer, VoteSerializer, QuestionResultPageSerializer
import random

@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def questions_view(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        questions = Question.objects.all().order_by('?')[:5].first()
        serializer = QuestionListPageSerializer(questions)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = QuestionListPageSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            question = serializer.save()
            return Response(QuestionListPageSerializer(question).data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

serializer

```
class QuestionListPageSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    question_text = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = serializers.DateTimeField()
    was_published_recently = serializers.BooleanField(read_only=True) # Serializer is smart enough to understand that was_published_recently is a method on Question
    code = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Question.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        for key, value in validated_data.items():
            setattr(instance, key, value)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to have a timer that is counted down on the page that has a question.

This seems more like something you should implement in JavaScript rather than in Django (something like this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_countdown.asp).

Any action handled is then sent to the Django backend through API calls by using ajax. Heres a tutorial on how to work do this https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html

Hope this helps or points you in the right direction